# Javascript autosubmit form when specific string detected in textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea, submit

Hopefully, a bit of a newbie JS question. (I searched & found some sort-of similar ones, but not quite this situation...) Ok, I have a simple form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="foo.php">
<textarea name="inputBox123"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1" />
</form>
```

Of course, the form has a normal submit button. But, in addition to that, I would like to have a code word like "okaygo" (or anything such string) such that, if the textarea contains this word (either if it is typed, pasted, etc.), then the form would auto-submit, just as though the button were pressed.

So, I figure I need some way to continually monitor the content of the text-area, and evaluate it against whether that string is present -- and if so submit. Can anyone show me how to do that, or at least point me in the right direction?

(Just for anyone wanting to know why... I work w/ some people who use scanners to enter form data. Usually they scan data into the form and click the submit button. But, they also said they could save time if they didn't always have to put the scanner down and click the submit button. So, I told them maybe I could come up w/ a barcode on the screen coded for some specific string like 12345678 or okaygonow, or whatever. So, the idea is, they scan their stuff, scan the barcode, the string appears in the form, it's detected by Javascript, and then the form submits & they don't have to even touch the keyboard / mouse. Anyway, that's the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form easily enough in code.  First give your form an id:

```
<form method="POST" id="myform" action="foo.php">
<textarea name="inputBox123"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1" />
</form>
```

Next add a onchange event on you input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1" onchange="myFunction(this); />
```

then in your function check the value every time the event fires:

```
function myFunction(input)
{ 
     if(input.value == 'okaygo')
     {
         // get the form by id
         var form = document.getElementById('myform');

        // submit the form
        form.submit();
     }
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you can also check the input and ignore upper or lower case by checking the comparison and making both values being compared lower by changing the if statement to do this:

```
if(input.value.toLowerCase() == 'okaygo')
{
    // same as above get form by id and submit it.
}
```

If you need to check input on a key up - then use the "onkeyup " event rather that the onchange event.

Comment: Thanks, will give something like this a try... Clarification: I'd tie 'myFunction' to the *textarea* in this example, correct? So, I assume it'd be something like "if (textareaID.value == 'word') etc."  (Or, really, not even an "if value =" clause, but maybe an indexOf, as this special code string will be just one small part of the whole textarea. But, anyway, I see what you're getting at here & hopefully can muddle together a solution (and will post one when I get it working).  -JD

Comment: Yes depending ob requirement indexOf can work as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, man. That helped point me where I needed to go. Here's one approach, in case anyone's searching for the same thing.  The form would be like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="myform" action="foo.php">
<textarea name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" oninput="myFunction(this);"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1" />
</form>
```

... and the Javascript would be like this:

```
function myFunction(val) {

    var testThis = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

    if ( testThis.indexOf("launch") > -1 ) {

        // get the form by id
        var form = document.getElementById('myform');

        // submit the form
        form.submit();

    }

}
```

In this way, it monitors the textarea and indeed submits the form when the specific vgalue is present (in this case the word "launch").